# Error when trying to deploy a smart contract using deploy-zksync

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, hardhat-deploy, zksync

I am getting the following error after running `yarn hardhat deploy-zksync`:

```
Running deploy script for the Greeter contract
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: Bytecode length in 32-byte words must be odd
    at hashBytecode (/Users/matifalcone/GMG/P2E/smart-contracts-sponsored-transactions/node_modules/zksync-web3/build/src/utils.js:205:15)
    at ContractFactory.getDeployTransaction (/Users/matifalcone/GMG/P2E/smart-contracts-sponsored-transactions/node_modules/zksync-web3/build/src/contract.js:42:55)
    at Deployer.estimateDeployGas (/Users/matifalcone/GMG/P2E/smart-contracts-sponsored-transactions/node_modules/@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy/src/deployer.ts:157:34)
    at async Deployer.estimateDeployFee (/Users/matifalcone/GMG/P2E/smart-contracts-sponsored-transactions/node_modules/@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy/src/deployer.ts:139:21)
    at async default_1 (/Users/matifalcone/GMG/P2E/smart-contracts-sponsored-transactions/deploy/deploy.ts:20:25)
    at async runScript (/Users/matifalcone/GMG/P2E/smart-contracts-sponsored-transactions/node_modules/@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy/src/plugin.ts:73:5)
    at async callDeployScripts (/Users/matifalcone/GMG/P2E/smart-contracts-sponsored-transactions/node_modules/@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy/src/plugin.ts:43:13)
    at async SimpleTaskDefinition.zkSyncDeploy [as action] (/Users/matifalcone/GMG/P2E/smart-contracts-sponsored-transactions/node_modules/@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy/src/task-actions.ts:5:5)
    at async Environment._runTaskDefinition (/Users/matifalcone/GMG/P2E/smart-contracts-sponsored-transactions/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:311:14)
    at async Environment.run (/Users/matifalcone/GMG/P2E/smart-contracts-sponsored-transactions/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:159:14)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

The code for the `deploy.ts` script is as follows:

```
import { Wallet, utils } from "zksync-web3";
import * as ethers from "ethers";
import { HardhatRuntimeEnvironment } from "hardhat/types";
import { Deployer } from "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy";

// An example of a deploy script that will deploy and call a simple contract.
export default async function (hre: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment) {
  console.log(`Running deploy script for the Greeter contract`);

  // Initialize the wallet.
  const wallet = new Wallet("<WALLET-PRIVATE-KEY>");

  // Create deployer object and load the artifact of the contract you want to deploy.
  const deployer = new Deployer(hre, wallet);
  const artifact = await deployer.loadArtifact("Greeter");

  // Estimate contract deployment fee
  const greeting = "Hi there!";
  const deploymentFee = await deployer.estimateDeployFee(artifact, [greeting]);

  // Deploy this contract. The returned object will be of a `Contract` type, similarly to ones in `ethers`.
  // `greeting` is an argument for contract constructor.
  const parsedFee = ethers.utils.formatEther(deploymentFee.toString());
  console.log(`The deployment is estimated to cost ${parsedFee} ETH`);

  const greeterContract = await deployer.deploy(artifact, [greeting]);

  //obtain the Constructor Arguments
  console.log("constructor args:" + greeterContract.interface.encodeDeploy([greeting]));

  // Show the contract info.
  const contractAddress = greeterContract.address;
  console.log(`${artifact.contractName} was deployed to ${contractAddress}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is normally return because the bytecode you're trying to deploy is not valid for zkSync. Have you installed and configured the hardhat-zksync-solc plugin, and compiled the contracts with it? See the [documentation here](https://v2-docs.zksync.io/api/hardhat/hardhat-zksync-solc.html)

Check if you have an `artifacts-zk` folder (this is created after compiling with `zksolc`) and also check if the generated bytecode in your contract JSON file (the same file that has the contract ABI) is not empty.

We identified an issue with some operating systems and released a fix. Make sure you're using zksolc version `1.3.8` (or higher) in your `hardhat.config.ts` file and use `@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-solc` version `0.3.15` (or higher).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am effectively compiling with `zksolc` BUT I do see the `bytecode` as `0x`. This is my `hardhat.config.ts`: https://gist.github.com/matias-gmg/78801e79d864afe73bebdd2c4d6b2117

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Can you share your Node.js/NPM, and your OS versions? We're trying to figure out what's causing this issue

Comment: Node v18.14.0 / NPM v9.3.1 / macOS Ventura Version 13.2.1 (22D68)

Comment: Marking this question as answered as effectively that's the problem I am having (the `bytecode` is being compiled as `0x` using `zksolc`). Anyway, I am tracking in another question the why of this.

Comment: we've released a fix for this specific issue. Make sure you're using zksolc version `1.3.8` in your `hardhat.config.ts` file and `@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-solc` version `0.3.15`